# Query where ALL associated records have attribute value X

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I have a query that counts associated records AND associated status

```
SELECT
  orders.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.shipment_status='CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as closed,
  COUNT(*) as shipment_count
FROM orders as po
JOIN shipments as s ON s.order_id = po.id 
GROUP BY po.id
```

I am attempting to query all orders, where **all** the shipments are `CLOSED`.

Essentially looking at the above, just returning when `closed = shipment_count` .

If I add an `AND` clause to the join then it will simply limit the number of shipments.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with a `HAVING` clause, which doesn't use the select attrs.

```
SELECT
  orders.id
FROM orders as po
JOIN shipments as s ON s.order_id = po.id
GROUP BY po.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.shipment_status='CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Leaving my answer up in case it helps others. Maybe better answers available to come from the community.